# windows phone 8.1 app installation deleting another app

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I have one application which is already installed on the phone and another application to be developed and to be installed on the phone. Is it a possibility that i can delete the first app automatically while the second app is getting installed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to update the app which exists already in the phone, you just need to update your app project and submit the xap file to store. When user downloads your app, the first app will be removed and the new app will be installed.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to delete an application from another, you should consider (if it is possible) to handle App1 as your first app and App2 as an update of App1.